# Runtime exception with Data Parallel Haskell / GHC 7.4.2

Tags: haskell, ghc, ghci, data-parallel-haskell

I'm trying to do some simple experiements with Data Parallel Haskell running, but I clearly have some options wrong. even when I try something very simple like

```
sumP [:1.0,2.0:]
```

I get an exception

```
Exception indexParr: out of bounds parallel array index; idx = 0, arr len = 0
```

Assume I have something set up wrongly - but ...

I get this same error both when trying to use GHCi, and when running a executable generated with GHC.

Answer (score 1):

You might be running into some of the limitations specified by the [DPH project status](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/GHC/Data_Parallel_Haskell#Project_status). Specifically

> Major limitations include the inability to mix vectorised and
>   non-vectorised code in a single Haskell module, the need to use a
>   feature-deprived, special-purpose Prelude for vectorised code, and a
>   lack of optimisations (leading to poor performance in some cases).

If you're just looking to make use of regular data parallelism, you can probably get away with [repa](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Numeric_Haskell%3a_A_Repa_Tutorial#Quick_Tour) (which is also recommended by the DPH page).